# Changing status of caller drops the call in twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I am building an application with twilio service. All functionality are working fine but when i want to place the caller on hold the call drops. I pass the call_SID to a script that updates the status of call, as soon as that script executes the caller drops off and put the agent to hold music. I have searched all over it but i am not getting any solution.

I have tried enqueue & dequeue the call but when i am changing the call status it drops the call.

Can anybody help how to achieve this hold functionality for user.

Comment: Have you tried the [Twilio Help](http://www.twilio.com/help) or talked to their [support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have mailed them lets see when they reply. Ok i have got the issue in my case the call sid i am providing to modify the url is callsid of parent call which initiated the call. I want to get the child callsid which i am not able to get. The twilio client js which i am using only provide callsid of parent not for child. Is there any way to get the child sid ?